# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate...SessionHiveMetaStoreClient, using derby, hive 2.1.1 and hadoop 2.7.3

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore, bigdata

I have this error when i try to launch hive shell:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Provide more information. 1) How was the installation done? 2) Did you add any properties to `hive-site.xml` ? 3) Was `hive` shell working before?

Comment: i add this property:
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
   <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true </value>
   <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore </description>
</property>

the hive shell is never working before